# Интерфейс удалённого сервера

Tags: сервер, telegram, бот

Мне предоставили готовый телеграм бот, то есть мне скинули ip сервер, пароль и логин. И я беспонятия что мне с этим делать. Надо доработать бот. Подключилась к серверу через ssh, но мне бы хотелось визуальное представление, то есть работать не с командной строкой, а с интерфейсом. Знаю, что в различных ide это можно сделать, но почему то не могу найти какую то адекватную инструкцию

Comment: Что за сервер? Доступ к папкам на сервере есть? На каком языке написан бот?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.